# empty() check not validating after POST

Tags: php

I'm setting a session variable in my `header.php` here:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['name'])) {
    ?>
    No name set! <br>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="textName"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submitName" value="Log in"/>
    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitName'])) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['textName'];

    }
}
```

and validating that the `name` variable is set on my index here:

```
<?php

include 'header.php';

if(!empty($_SESSION['name'])){
    ?>
<a href="session_kill.php">Log out</a>
<?php
}

?>
```

I can confirm that the session variable exists because the `logout` link appears.

After submitting a name via the form, the session variable updates but the `empty()` check doesn't reoccur, meaning the `textarea` stays on the page unless I refresh.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: you have to process data before displaying it, otherwise you display the unprocessed data... say you have a log in form, you display the login form before checking if the user logged in, then you will have to refresh the page to check if you were logged in or not.

Comment: why not use isset();?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take this part:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitName'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['textName'];

}
```

above this:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['name'])) {}
```

When you submit the form, at the beginning; since the session is empty and hence the form remains there and then the session is initialized. And when you refresh the page the session check works.

Comment: Glad to help. Explanation added :)